# Designing a "trial before signup" system securely

Tags: authentication, web-applications, phoenix-framework

How can I implement a "trial before signup" user system safely?

My thoughts so far are:

- User clicks "Try product"

  - Controller creates new `user`

    - sets `is_trial = true`
    - sets `trial_id = UUID()`
  - Set session/cookie `trial_id = user.trial_id`
- Future visits check session/cookie for `trial_id`, load user if present and found else redirect to signup/start-trial page.

I think this will function fine barring two people generating the same UUID, but my worry is a user could edit their cookies `trial_id` and spoof their way into someone else's (admittedly also trial) account.

I know the chance of someone guessing someone else's UUID is pretty small, but it's not impossible.

Is this how these systems are normally designed? How can I add more security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the method outlined is correct along with adding something such as JTW to either sign (to prevent tampering) or sign and encrypt the cookies.